# How to get UILocalNotification cancellation event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am showing a local notification when an event occurs.If user select "View details" of UIlocalNotification we can get that event in didReceiveLocalNotification. But is there any option if user selcet "Close" ? . I checked documentation. Nothing i found. Any suggestion you have ? please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the users cancels the notification, what he probably wants to say is that he's not interested in it currently. That has the effect that your application does not even enter foreground and therefore has no chance of responding to this event.